# is it posible to auto increment variable name after a while loop?

Tags: php

I need to create a php file with a hundred variables, which are all identical except for their id.

PHP Code

```
$var1 = get_input('myvar1');
$var2 = get_input('myvar2');
$var3 = get_input('myvar3');
$var4 = get_input('myvar4');
...
$var30 = get_input('myvar30');
```

I wonder if it is possible to create only one line as a model, and is replicated 30 times?

Comment: Maybe you should look into using an `array` which is a whole bunch of variables stored as one name with an index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking after something like this :

```
$vars = [];
for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    $vars[] = get_input('myvar' . $i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a job for [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

```
$var = array_fill(1, 30, 'myvar');
```

use the array key as your "id"

Comment: does not work for OP's use case. The array values are not just `myvar` but instead is grabbed using get_input function with variable keys

Comment: I like Dagon's answer better.

Comment: @khuderm based on the description of the problem "I need to create a php file with a hundred variables, which are all identical except for their id." it works, i assume the code was a failed attempt. there is no native php function `get_input()`

Comment: @Dagon lol it is pretty obvious that OP wrote a function called `get_input()` which returns values based on different keys. Hence filling the arrays with `myvar` does not work. As for the piece you quoted, it is pretty obvious to me that he is referring to the variable name instead of the values.

Comment: @Dagon lol decide what? whether or not he wrote a function called `get_input()`? you can CLEARLY see that each variable has different values which are returned from `get_input()` function using different keys. Sure your solution is great for creating arrays with same values but but inherently slower compared to mine or @Max's solution. OP would still need to iterate over the array to fill it with values from `get_input()`. So, you waste resources pre-filling the array when it is going to be replaced anyway. There is 0 logical reason to have 100 different variables with the EXACT same values.

Comment: The only thing your answer satisfies is "create only one line" and that is not even what OP meant.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with arrays when you can create the variables like so. The variables names are also set dynamically just like the values.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    ${'var' . $i} = get_input('myvar' . $i);
}
```